# Remove word only for first line using php

Tags: php

I have text:

```
I have new blue car
I have new red and blue cars
```

How remove what word i want from first line using php?

Ex:

```
        $text = preg_replace("/^(blue>){1}/", "", $text);
```

The result should be:

```
I have new car
I have new red and blue cars
```

And i want example for remove "p br " it is posible.

```
<p></p><br/>I have new blue car
I have new red and blue cars
```

Comment: How use only for first line? the text is longer and contains more tag. enter text in textarea and need to edit tags frontline

Answer (score 0):

The following will find the first row, replace the 'blue' word on that line with nothing (remove it), strip tags and remove leading/trailing space.

- Will only remove whole words, e.g. not 'blue' in 'blues'
- Will not remove word from following lines if not found in first line
- Will not strip tags from following lines

Code:

```
$text = "<p></p><br/>I have new blue car
I have new <b>red<b> and blue cars";
$word = 'blue';

$text = preg_replace_callback(
    '/.*$/m', // Match single line
    function ($matches) use ($word) {
        // Remove word (\b = word boundary), strip tags and trim off whitespace
        return trim(
            strip_tags(
                preg_replace('/\b' . $word. '\s*\b/', '', $matches[0])
            )
        );
    },
    $text,
    1 // Match first line only
);

echo $text, PHP_EOL;
```

Output:

```
I have new car
I have new <b>red<b> and blue cars
```